# how to query mongoose with multiple query params via an object or an array?

Tags: angularjs, mongoose, mean-stack

I want to send js object to the backend or an array so that in the backend code ( below ) I can use the values and make a search in the mongodb ( using mongoose ) to get the data.

server code

```
exports.prioritySearch = function(req, res, next, id) {
  console.log( 'prioritySearch-API  id = ', id); 

  console.log( ' req.params  = ', req.params); 
  // console.log( ' req  = ', req);   
  // Property.find({ Left_VM_P : 'true' }).exec(function(err, properties) {

  Property.find({ id : 'true' }).exec(function(err, properties) {    
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).send({
        message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
      });
    } else {
      res.jsonp(properties);
    }
  });
};
```

Angular Service that calls this api

```
.factory('prioritySearchSvc', function($q, _, $http, currentUrl, TodayDateSvc) {  
    console.log('186-S---- inside SinglePropertyDataService ');


var Priority = 'Left_VM_P'; 

    var deferred = $q.defer(),
        url = currentUrl+"/api/prioritySearch/"+Priority;
```

This below code works but next one don't which I dont understand why.

// below query works

```
Property.find({ Left_VM_P : 'true' }).exec(function(err, properties) {
```

// but i want below query to work coz i want to change the id parameter so I can modify each time what key is searched for, here id = Left_VM_P  but why isn't it working..

```
Property.find({id : 'true' }).exec(function(err, properties) {
```

Comment: what do you want to do? its not clear

Comment: @RaviShankar  Basically im not able to retrive the data from monogo using the query above. I've shown what is workign and what is not working.